# Is it possible to use translate method to swap out entire picture? ANGULAR

Tags: angular, translate

trying to change image on button click. the button is connected to the transalte function to change language on page. I would like to change the pictures aswell using this mehtod if possible. (new to angular) would appreciate help.

html.

```
   <image sexternalResourcesRequired="true"[attr.src] ='{{imgTranslate| translate}}'  [attr.xlink:href]="contentBase + '/img/img.jpg'preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" />
```

translate.ts

```
imgTransalte: " translateTothisImg"
```

Comment: What if you try `<img src='{{imgTransalte |translate}}'` ?

Comment: sorry just realised it was a svg image tag not a regular img tag.. so img src doesnt work :/

Comment: Hello The Searcher! Did you find some way to switch an image when selecting a language with ngx translate?, I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is a little bit late but I find a solution to this problem.
In my case, I have the images in the assets folder.
So I create an object that looks like

```
{
  img: {
   en: '../assets/images/en/imageName.png',
   gr: '../assets/images/gr/imageName.png'
  }
}
```

The translate service has a function named `onLangChange` and I subscribe to it in order to get the selected language.

So in my template, I wrote

```
<img [src]="item.img[currentLang]">
```

Now if you change language your image should change.
This works for me and I hope that I have help.

Thanks